# Where in the .NET class library is IAudioEndpointVolume located?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, controls, volume

I'm trying to write an application that controls the system volume on Windows 7 but I can't find any documentation on where IAudioEndpointVolume is located in the .NET class library. What is the full path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Core Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (where [IAudioEndpointVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is located) is [not native to the .NET Framework.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, you can use [this Codeplex project](http://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/), which provides .NET wrappers for the Core Audio API.

Comment: How do I implement this in C#?
`code`
IAudioEndpointVolume volume = ???;

float* pfLevelDB = null;

int result = volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel(out *pfLevelDB);

Comment: Study the CodePlex project. I haven't used it, so I don't know.  You will need to take the assembly that's in the CodePlex project, and reference it in your own project.  Documentation is included with the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

`IAudioEndpointVolume` is part of the operating system API's, it's in a C++ dll.  It doesn't exist as part of the .Net BCL.  You could P/Invoke into it if you wish, but there isn't a .Net wrapper unless someone else has written a 3rd party version.